# IOS show UIViewController from addMessageFromRemoteNotification in AppDelegate

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, appdelegate

How is it possible to show an `UIViewController` (which is not the first one in the navigation) from the `addMessageFromRemoteNotification` in the `AppDelegate`?

I tried this:

```
UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController*)_window.rootViewController;
ChatViewController *chatViewController = (ChatViewController*)[navigationController.viewControllers  objectAtIndex:1];
```

but it doesn't work, it allways shows the first `Viewcontroller` not the second one.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to add:

```
[navigationController popToViewController:chatViewController animated:NO];
```